# Bootstrap tooltip isn't working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

My JavaScript:

```html
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('a[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();
    });
​</script>
```

And my HTML:

```html
<br><br><br>This is an example of a sentence with a
<a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="This is the tooltip!">tooltip</a>!
```

This doesn't show the Bootstrap 2.0 tooltip but shows some default one.

Comment: You need to describe your problem in more detail as there's not enough here to say exactly what's wrong.  What do you mean by default one?  Post a screenshot of your tooltip.  Post more code including the javascript files you include on your page, the css you've included and any imbedded javascript.

Comment: I already have..that's the bit thats relevant, why do u want me to post the whole code?

Comment: @AliGajani it would help if you posted your markup, just to see what js scripts are included and what is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding the code in footer. it worked for me! for some reason it doesn't work in header!

Comment: Just to add a quick A. You have to add all jQuery functions after the main jQuery library has loaded. they should also be called within  the $(document).ready() method.

Answer (score 5):

Let's say you've declared your tooltips declared as follows:

```html
<a href="#" rel="tooltip" class="tip" title="Rating:' + rating + '">'+ name +'</a>
```

In the same file, make sure you include:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('.tip').tooltip();
</script>
```

Note that you should either refer to this code after the HTML it references, or wrap it in

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.tip').tooltip();
    });
</script>
```

Also note that the jQuery selector refers to a class of tooltips and not just the id of one tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all the css styles for the .tooltip class loaded.

Without these the tooltip may be displayed outside the visible part of your browser window.